# Why in Linux the order of modal windows changes when you click on the owner

Tags: java, linux, windows, javafx, cross-platform

Good day. I am engaged in cross-platform development of desktop applications on JavaFX for Windows and Linux. The application is the main stage which is the owner for all subsequent open modal windows. When working in Window, when you click on the main stage, all windows lose focus and their order does not change, which I think is right.

Windows open with focus on the last window (Windows OS)
[image]

Mouse click on the main stage, focus is lost, window order has not changed (Windows OS)
[image]

In the Linux operating system, when you click on the main stage, all modal windows lose focus and their order changes, which should not be.

Windows open with focus on the last window (Linux OS)
[image]

Mouse click on the main stage, focus is lost, window order
changed (Linux OS)
[image]

Tell me what may be the reason for changing the order of modal windows in Linux with the loss of focus. All open modal windows have an owner main stage.

Modal window settings when opening:

```
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setFullScreen(false);
    initOwner(owner);
```

OS Windows - 7

OS Linux - Astra Linux Debian GNU/Linux CE 2.12.21 (Codename: Orel, Release: 2.12.21)

The graphics subsystem on Linux operates using the **Xorg** graphics server.

**Fly** desktop, window manager **fly-wm**

Java 8, JavaFX 8

Comment: Please also specify the window manager that's being used.

Comment: Updated a question

Comment: Is it at all possible that you could try using JavaFX 8 (since you're using Java 8)? JavaFX 2.0 is _old_, outdated, and possibly has bugs that were fixed in newer versions. Of course, JavaFX 8 is also relatively old. If you can use Java 11+ then you could try using JavaFX 14.0.1, which is the latest release as of this comment.

Comment: I can’t upgrade to a newer version at this time. Sorry, JavaFx I have 8 versions